# UITableView with UIPanGestureRecognizer causes "jumping" touch

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

The case: https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ios_jumping_y.git

[image]

**The Container**

```
class ContainerController: UIViewController { 
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!   
    @IBOutlet weak var foregroundTopSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var foregroundBottomSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

The container is connected to the UITableViewController to its right.

**What I want to do**

The user scrolls the table and when he reaches the top I want to move the table down with the same movement. So I simply change the top/bottom space of the container view. However this causes the table to jump.

```
class MainController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    var gotStart: Bool = true

    var startTouch: CGPoint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.bounces = false

        self.panRecognizer = self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer
        self.panRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "pan:")
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(self.panRecognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func pan(rec:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if let parent = self.parentViewController as? ContainerController {

            var y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
            var touch = rec.locationInView(self.view)

            // JUMPING y
            println(touch.y)

            if y == -64 {

                if self.gotStart  || y < -64 || y > -64 {

                    self.startTouch = touch
                    self.gotStart = false

                } else {

                    if rec.state == .Changed {

                        var changedVerticalHeight = (self.startTouch.y - touch.y)*(-1)

                        if changedVerticalHeight <= parent.view.frame.size.height && touch.y >= changedVerticalHeight {

                            parent.foregroundTopSpace.constant = changedVerticalHeight
                            parent.foregroundBottomSpace.constant = -changedVerticalHeight
                        }

                    } else if rec.state == .Ended {

                        parent.foregroundTopSpace.constant = 0
                        parent.foregroundBottomSpace.constant = 0

                        self.gotStart = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Any ideas whats wrong? There has to be some problem with the container view because when I move the table view directly there is no jumping.

Comment: I have your modified project if you have any doubt in my answer. I can send you without problem.

Comment: @VictorSigler yes please make a pull request on github to show me the changes. I accepted your answer :)

Comment: I've done the pull request in GitHub, let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I going to clarify some things in my answer before I put the complete code

1. You can use the function `scrollViewWillEndDragging` to know where exactly the `contentOffset` is going to, see the below code :

   ```
   override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
      println(targetContentOffset.memory.y)        
   }
   ```
2. You can use the function `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to know when the scroll has finished it.

Then you can merge the two above tips to accomplish your goal in the following way:

```
class MainController: UITableViewController {

   var position : CGFloat!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()       
   }

   override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {  
      // Save where the contentOffset go        
      position = targetContentOffset.memory.y
   }   

   override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

       // If reach the top or more than the top when the user move the scroll
       if (position < 0) {               
           var to = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 213
           scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: to), animated: true)
       }        
   }    

   // Default table stuff, not related to problem  

   /* Here comes the rest of your code of TableView */    
}
```

I remove some code for your project relative to the `panGestureRecognizer` and bounces to test.

In the line `var to = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 213` you can add the `position` variable or the value you want, I put `213` only to test the down movement.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the location from `self.view` system coordinates. The `UITableViewController` use a table view like self.view. So the origin (x:0 y:0) start to move when the user scrolling.

You have to user a static system coordinates. Use the `UIViewController` and `UITableView` `panGestureRecognizer` property for print position correctly and get the scrolling:

1. Create a new `UIViewController`.
2. Add `UITableview` and setup `AutoLayout`.
3. Connect the `IBOutlet` with the `UITableView`

Add the code to the `UIViewController` class:

```
var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.panRecognizer = tableView?.panGestureRecognizer;
    self.panRecognizer .addTarget(self, action: "pan:")
    tableView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.panRecognizer)

}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func pan(rec:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    println(rec.locationInView(self.view).y)
}
```

You can download the project example [here](http://cl.ly/3i3O3t382V2r).

If you just need control the scrolling, remember that [UIScrollView delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:):

```
optional func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

can help you. It's a cleaner a simpler solution:

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for response, however I was a but unclear about my problem. Check out my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that exactly what you want:

```
import UIKit

class MainController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        let beginingContentOffset: CGFloat = -64
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < beginingContentOffset {
            scrollView.bounces = false
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05, animations: { () -> Void in
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
                }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                scrollView.bounces = true
            })
        }
    }

    // Default table stuff, not related to problem

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell_ : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL_ID") as? UITableViewCell
        if(cell_ == nil){
            cell_ = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CELL_ID")
        }

        cell_!.textLabel!.text = "Row " + String(indexPath.row)

        return cell_!
    }
}
```

P.S. That "-64" value. It's margin from storyboard. You can uncheck margins for constraint and it will be "0". It will be much clearest